# Use same RecyclerViewAdapter for 2 RecyclerView's

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm having some issues on implementing 2 `RecyclerView's` to the same `RecyclerViewAdapter` actually in my `main.class` i have 2 `RecyclerView's` one work's properly and it's made of **buttons** that contain some strings and i have also another `RecyclerView` where i would be able to put the string data from the **buttons** `onClick` but i can't get how can i implement another `RecyclerView` to `RecyclerViewAdapter` i have yet the `onClick` method on buttons so i have just to get data from them and put them to the new `RecyclerView` but i don't know how to do it.

Any suggestion on how can i do?

Here is the screenshot of my layout with two `recyclerView's`

[image]

While here is the code from the `RecyclerViewAdapter` the second `recyclerView` to implement is called recyclerlist_item.xml and it contain 3 TextView's called "Desc,Qta,Imp"

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Item> mArrayList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonName);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }


public static class ListHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView desc;
        public TextView qta;
        public TextView imp;


    public ListHolder(View listView) {
        super(listView);

        desc = listView.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
        qta = listView.findViewById(R.id.Qta);
        imp = listView.findViewById(R.id.Imp);


    }


}

    public Adapter(ArrayList<Item> itemList){
            mArrayList = itemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                Item currentItem = mArrayList.get(position);

                holder.mTextView.setText(currentItem.getBtnName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArrayList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me get the question straight, you want any items clicked in the bottom RecyclerView to appear in the top one?

If so try something like this:

```
List<Item> selectedItemList = new ArrayList<>();

Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(itemArrayList);
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener(){

    @override
    void onItemClick(int position){
        Item item = itemArrayList.get(position);

        if( !selectedItemList.contains(item) ){
            selectedItemList.add( item );
            topAdapter.notifyItemInserted(selectedItemList.size() - 1);
        }
    }

});
```

In this example *topAdapter* is a new adapter you need to write and back with the *selectedItemList* List. That adapter should use your *ListHolder* ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create **two objects of the same adapter** and pass the different **RecyclerView** to the two objects. A simple example is given below

```
    private TempRecycleViewAdapter tempRecycleViewAdapter1, tempRecycleViewAdapter2;


    tempRecycleViewAdapter1= new TempRecycleViewAdapter (this);
    tempRecycleViewAdapter1.setAdapter(tempRecycleViewAdapter1);
    tempRecycleViewAdapter1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    

    tempRecycleViewAdapter2= new TempRecycleViewAdapter (this);
    tempRecycleViewAdapter2.setAdapter(tempRecycleViewAdapter2);
    tempRecycleViewAdapter2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```